# GMSMapStyle not working for map styling Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps

I am trying to change my google Map styling to silver style as given in this documentation -

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling

I am using json for silver style but its not updating somehow.

I tried the same code given in google documentation.

```
func UpdateMapStyle() {
        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "paper", withExtension: "json") {
                self.googleMap.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
                print("Changed")
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
    }
```

I call that above code from viewWillAppear after this below line -

```
self.googleMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: currentCoordinate, zoom: 14)
UpdateMapStyle()
```

I don't get any error. And it doesn't even go in else or catch block. I am getting styleURL and print changed is getting printed but map is still showing normal style map. I kept my view controller.swift and paper.json in same folder. Please help!!

Comment: have you tried to import your jSON to link you added? Does it work?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik yes importing json in that link works

Answer (score 2):

Google Map documentation says:

> Styling works only on the kGMSTypeNormal map type.
>
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/hiding-features

This is your challenge!

The code I've tested and worked on the example below, hope this help.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gMaps: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This is important
        // Styling works only on the kGMSTypeNormal map type.
        gMaps.mapType = .normal

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = gMaps
    }

    @IBAction func changeTheme(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                gMaps.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mapview is an IBOutlet, I don't want to update whole view with my map view. And I moved code to loadView but still it is not working.

Comment: I tried updating on a button click also, just to test. That is also not working.

Comment: @RichaSrivastava If you haven't found the solution yet seems like when we create .json file in xcode it adds some code in .json file by default if you have those comments remove them ( i had the similar issue i had comments in my style.json fiel ).